# How to put the down arrow of an accordion-button in the left

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm coding a website in Arabic language content.
Problem: the down arrow of an accordion button should be in the far left.
This is my code:

```html
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   
   <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
      <button dir="rtl" class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne">
        السؤال الأول؟
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div dir="rtl" id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">الجواب على سؤالك الأول</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. The easiest way to do that is to use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992) (icon looks like `<>` in the toolbar). You'll need to provide a CDN link to Bootstrap 5 in the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `margin-right:auto` to the `::after` element which relates to the arrow; along with removing the `margin-left` that is applied by Bootstrap. See below.

```css
.accordion-button::after {
  margin-left:0!important;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Code -->
<div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
      <button dir="rtl" class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
        السؤال الأول؟
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">الجواب على سؤالك الأول</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nrub90zy/)**

Answer (score 0):

It's also worked for me.

```
.accordion-button::after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.7rem;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following CSS.

```css
.accordion-button {
  justify-content: end !important;
}

.accordion-button::after {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   
<div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
      <button dir="rtl" class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne">
        السؤال الأول؟
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div dir="rtl" id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">الجواب على سؤالك الأول</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```